# Is it possible to click button class in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

when I use `browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".LkLjZd ScJHi OzU4dc  ").click()`,

`Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".LkLjZd ScJHi OzU4dc  "}`

This error occurs despite of element is that `<button class="LkLjZd ScJHi OzU4dc  " jsaction="click:TiglPc" jsname="gxjVle" style="font-family: Roboto, &quot;Noto Sans KR&quot;, sans-serif;">total review</button>`

how to click the butten....

Comment: dude, your code should be this `browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".LkLjZd .ScJHi .OzU4dc  ").click()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.='total review']").click()
```

You can click on it by it's text value most of it's identifiers seems dynamic

Answer (score 0):

you can use the xpath of the element.

1. Install xpath Helper in your chrome.
2. Refresh the page or close it and enter again.
3. Click on addon from the toolbar.
4. Shift + click the element you needed.
5. Than browser.find_element_by_xpath()

PS: If it's a long string you can cut the start of it and replace with another /.